# Getting screen coordinate of action bar menu item for creating introduction screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was wondering, if there is any possibility of getting the screen coordinates of an action bar menu item?

As I would like to create an introduction screen, to draw an arrow pointing to the desired action bar menu item, so that the user knows where to start.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I did it:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId().equals(R.id.my_menu_item)) {
        View menuView = findViewById(R.id.menu_item_search);
        int[] location = new int[2];
        menuView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        int menuViewX = location[0];
        int menuViewY = location[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: This relies on the widget having a particular ID. That may be true in cases where you are creating your custom action bar contents. It will not be the case for all situations, particularly where you are using things from the Android SDK, like `SearchView` or `ShareActionProvider`, where widget IDs, to the extent they exist, are internal implementation details and are subject to change.

Comment: This also relies on the user clicking a button in the action bar, which won't work in the case of what the person is asking here.

Comment: To clarify this answer you maybe add some sentence that your answer assumes that your ActionBar menu items are custom created and given an id. @Rob you can call the those lines of code anywhere in your activity. There is no need to click a button in the action bar.

Answer (score 1):

Presently, there is no documented and supported means for doing this, except for your own custom action layouts or action views. There is no API to retrieve ordinary contents of the action bar (home affordance, title, regular items).

ShowcaseView, as mentioned in the other answer, probably does some undocumented/unsupported things for this, such as traversing the `View` hierarchy to get at these widgets. That's risky, insofar as future versions of Android, or manufacturer/ROM modder changes to Android, may break that logic.

Comment: is there still not way to find out the coordinates of action bar menu items?

Comment: @penduDev: Nothing documented and supported, last I checked.

Comment: is there any way to find it out now?

Comment: @KishyNivas: Not really, last I checked, but I have not looked into this in quite some time. Sorry!