# Find position of MenuItem dynamically

Tags: java, android

I have a menu with all items' `showAsAction` set to `ifRoom`. Now I want to get the exact position (x,y) of the center of any of these menu items.

I first thought of getting this information from the underlying views, but I don't know how to reliably access the view of a specific menu item.

In `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
MenuItem someItem = menu.findItem(R.id.some_action);
// someItem.getX();
// someItem.getY();
```

I'd expect these coordinates to be relative to the application's `Toolbar`. In this case I also need access to `someItem.get{Width,Height}()` to calculate the center coordinates.

An example menu:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" 
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_example"
    android:title="@string/action_example"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_example"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Try to use this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631806/getting-screen-coordinate-of-action-bar-menu-item-for-creating-introduction-scre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use the underlying activity to find the instanciated view.

```
View menuItemView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_search);
```

Then the position can be extracted relative to the toolbar by using `View.getLocationInWindow(intArr)`, which returns (x,y) relative to the view's window.

```
int[] itemWindowLocation = new int[2];
menuItemView.getLocationInWindow(itemWindowLocation);

int[] toolbarWindowLocation = new int[2];
toolbar.getLocationInWindow(toolbarWindowLocation);

int itemX = itemWindowLocation[0] - toolbarWindowLocation[0];
int itemY = itemWindowLocation[1] - toolbarWindowLocation[1];
int centerX = itemX + menuItemView.getWidth() / 2;
int centerY = itemY + menuItemView.getHeight() / 2;
```